# How do you create an if statement that doesn't evaluate?

Tags: python

If I have variables `x` and `y` defined, how do I create a stub `if` statement that evaluates whether `x` is less than `y` and does not do anything, even if the condition is true?

Comment: Why would you want to put nothing in there? If you don't use the output of the evaluation you could just omit if from your code.

Comment: You mean, like, using `pass`?

Answer (score 1):

This has a condition for if x is less than y and does nothing

```py
if x < y:
    pass
```

`pass` is used as a placeholder and nothing happens when `pass` is executed. If you want to learn more about the `pass` statement, you can check out https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/pass-statement.